# Why shouldn't I use a field with a "set" datatype? Alternative layouts?

Tags: sql, mysql, types

I've been designing my database layout and I guess I need a way to place multiple entries in a single field. I want to create a row for each student in the database, and I want one of the fields to contain their classes. I don't want to do a bunch of separate fields because there is not a set amount of classes a student can have, it can vary. I was [reading up](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html) on the `SET` datatype and read the paragraph about why not to use `SET`. I was wondering if anyone could make a more "english" explanation of this, or if it actually ok to use then tell me so. If it's not, could anyone suggest a better layout for the current situation? Much appreciated, as always!

Comment: Do not do this. Do not ever store multiple values in a single field. Never. Ever. Ever.

Comment: @Adam there are times when it makes sense, especially if your database is geared towards fulltext searches and the column already has a full text index.

Comment: @cyberwiki: How would a full text index be more effective (or faster) on non-normalized data than on normalized data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to store classes as a separate entity. For that, you need another table to store the classes, and a third table linking the two tables:

students: id, name, age, ...

classes: id, name, time, professor, ...

student_class: student_id, class_id

Then you'd use JOIN queries to retrieve the data.

Comment: +100. **Do not store multiple values in a single database field. Ever.**

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Thanks for your vote; however, I think there are times when storing multiple values in a single field is ... acceptable. If you won't ever need to do any queries involving the individual values, for example (very rare!). Good programming, like life itself, involves the use of good discernment, not just following a set of rules.

Comment: I have to say, I like this better. This fits better with the database structure I already had in mind. Thanks very much Mark.

Comment: True enough (that development requires being pragmatic, not dogmatic), but situations where storing multiple values in a field would be acceptable are so rare (and situations where it would be *preferable* is even more rare, if it even happens) that it doesn't really seem worth the effort in finding them.

Answer (score 0):

With a SET, you have to predefine all possible values.  You probably want a TEXT type datatype and separate values with some delimiter (like a semi-colon or other).

Comment: Boo. Comma-delimited fields are **EVIL**. Don't do it.

Comment: I agree that comma-delimited fields are evil, but based on his specific question this seems like the best option.  If it must be in one table, I would set up separate fields in my table for CourseOne, CourseTwo, CourseThree... but this is not what he wants (specifically says he wants it in one field of same table).  I also assumed he does not want a separate table with AutoId, CourseName, StudentId and link this to the student table...though that is probably the actual best solution...

Comment: separate fiels would be wrong, too.  It needs a separate table.